# Override the default Count Queryable extensions method for NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, select, nhibernate, count

I'm using NHibernate to Linq, and I've got an queryable that's been filtered, ordered, and projected.
I'm using a third party library to consume the IQueryable, where it handles pagination and count in its own extension method 
(Telerik Kendo MVC, `QueryableExtensions.ToDataSourceResult(this IQueryable enumerable, DataSourceRequest request)`).

The problem I'm running into is on the Count (being called in the ToDataSourceResult black box). I get the exception `QuerySyntaxException, "A recognition error occurred."` Google searches suggest the problem is calling count on a projected query. ([Google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhusers/wrOx1CIc4aY) and related [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262271/nhibernate-linq-query-with-projection-and-count-error), amongst others)

The suggestion that NH could throw away the projection before calling Count lead me to try to do just that by extending and registering new generators using `BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod` and `DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry`. But all the examples I find online are for adding new functionality, not to replace it.

Is there a way to override/replace the Count method NH handles so I can manually remove the projection?

A side question: Is there any official documentation for extending NHibernate-to-Linq? I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465866/linq-to-nhibernate-compareto-not-supported/11469134#11469134)

**EDIT**

Here's what I've tried so far, and I don't hit the new extension method. I'm obviously new to this...

```
public class InteumLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public InteumLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
        : base()
    {
        RegisterGenerator(ReflectionHelper.GetMethod(() => Queryable.Count<object>(null)), new NHibernateCountGenerator());
    }
}

public class NHibernateCountGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
{
    public NHibernateCountGenerator()
    {
        SupportedMethods = new[]
        { 
            ReflectionHelper.GetMethod(() => NHibernateCount.InteumCount<object>(null))
        };
    }

    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, Expression targetObject, ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments, HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        return treeBuilder.Count(visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression());
    }
}

public static class NHibernateCount
{
    public static int InteumCount<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        //  TODO: Remove projection from query

        return query.Count();
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**
Turns out I missed the part where it's calling Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.Count(IQueryable) instead of Queryable.Count<>(IQueryable<>). Made some changes, still, I'm not hitting the HqlGenerator, though I'm still not sure it should hit the generator at all...

Comment: Ok, so as I'm getting a feel for how this all works, it's seems to be making sense that I'm not hitting this code. Count isn't something where execution is deferred and returns an expression tree, it consumes the tree and returns a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

I already resolved this kind of need by wrapping IQueryable. After all it is just an interface.

For example, in a lambda project, Oracle was used with "select in" statement limited to 1000 values. I decided to wrap ISession in order to wrap IQueryable for developers without any customer changes (non intrusive).
Before IQueryable evaluation as IEnumerable by NHibernate, I replaced the expression to change all Contains call to a "partition contains" : (.Contains(...) && .Contains(...) && .Contains(...) && ...).

In your case, you can do the same on IQueryable evaluation to single value (IQueryable.Execute). Detect if it is a Count expression... apply your changes for expression using expression visitor and finally delegate the evaluation of modified expression to NHibernate.